# JSON Vulnerability Protection using express JS

Tags: json, node.js, security, express

I would like to know how can I use JSON Vulnerability Protection with express.js.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx

The problem is I used to write res.send(jsonObj) from controllers, which will sent data directly to the client.
But I want to intercept the response and modify it with something and send to the client. The client can then undo the modification and retrieve the original data.

I saw the res.format function, but it is not working as for my need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I ended up doing this:

```
    app.use(function (req, res, next){
        var actualSend = res.send;
        res.send = function (data) {
            if (typeof data == "object") {
                var strData = expressOptions.jsonPrefix + JSON.stringify(data);
                res.set('Content-Type', 'text/json');
                actualSend.call (res, strData);
            } else {
                actualSend.call (res, data);
            }
        };
        next();
    });
```

Where expressOptions.jsonPrefix is the prefix I wanted.
I added it before my route configurations.

Answer (score 3):

I was using `res.json` instead of `res.send` to send JSON, so I modified the code from your answer thus:

```
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.json = function (data) {
      var strData = typeof data == 'object' ? JSON.stringify(data) : data;
      strData = expressOptions.jsonPrefix + strData;
      res.set('Content-Type', 'text/json');
      res.send.call(res, strData);
    };
    next();
  });
```

Although I've implemented this "just to be sure", I don't think this is a serious vulnerability. If you read [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/), which is linked from [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) (which is where I think you got your inspiration to write your Express middleware), it seems that the JSON Vulnerability doesn't exist in "modern" browsers, as in, as far back as IE 6 and FireFox 3.

So I'm not sure why [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is telling people to implement this protection these days. Would appreciate if someone enlightened me in the comments! :)